Using Chakra UI, how do I transform grid A,B,C horizontally to B,A,C vertically responsive
I have a desktop design that looks like this - cards stacked horizontally:
A  B  C
I would like to transform this responsively for mobile widths using Chakra UI like this vertically:

B
A
C

How can I achieve this using Chakra UI?
